# OSX su command issue

Tags: macos, osx-lion, su

So I cant get `su` command to work on a terminal. All I do is type "su" and press enter, it asks for the password and I enter my currently logged in user password. It always gives this error. I swear this used to work earlier, not sure what happened.

```
su: Sorry
```

I am running a Mac OSX 10.7.1 (Lion). Anyone know what could be wrong? I am entering the right password.

Comment: I got it working, found it here - http://serverfault.com/questions/43362/su-not-working-on-mac-os-x

Comment: You might want to turn [your comment](http://serverfault.com/q/43362/58481) into an answer, then accept it. _It proved useful to me._

Answer (score 87):

```
sudo su
```

will do the trick in Mac Os X terminal :)

Answer (score 11):

There is no root account on mac osx. Just go `sudo bash` then type the command or commands you want as root.

Comment: -1.  Of course there is a root account.  "root" is shown as a file owner in many places. See Nehemias Herrera's correct answer below.

Comment: did you mean "the root account is not enabled by default, you have to manually enable it to use it"? here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528

Answer (score 1):

If sudo stops working because permission to read sudoers is missing, this solution from [kahisv.com](http://kashiv.com/2012/01/26/when-sudo-doesnt-work/) solves the problem:

Check if the permissions are still correct, that's how it should be:

```
$ ls -lad / /private /private/etc
d--xrwxr-t+  36 root  wheel  1292 25 sty 12:34 /
```

If this is wrong in your case, boot in Single-User Mode (hold cmd+s while booting) and enter theese commands:

```
# /sbin/fsck -fy
# /sbin/mount -wu /
# /bin/chmod 1775 /
# /bin/sync
# exit
```